# Progressive histograms with Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote a little Scala+Spark code that reads a large CSV file and calculates all of the column pair histograms (Separate histogram for (col1, col1), (col1, col2), (col1, col3), etc.), and stores the results progressively on a database (Redis) for other applications to use.

Can I do something similar with Spark-SQL?
I'm able to get data into a Dataframe and calculate the histograms, however I'm getting the final results only.

The data can be quite large so I'd like the other applications to be able to work on partial results while the histograms are being calculated (Histograms of `N` rows where `N` is the number of rows Spark was able to process so far).

Edit:
Code example of what I have so far:

```
val params = Map("url" -> "jdbc:vertica:someAddress", "dbtable" -> "schema.mytable")
val jdbc = sqlContext.load("jdbc", params)
val columns = jdbc.columns
val columnPairs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[(String, String)]()
for (i <- 0 to columns.size-1){
    for (j <- i to columns.size-1){
        columnPairs += ((columns(i), columns(j)))
    }
}
val histograms = columnPairs.map{case(first, second) => 
    enter code herejdbc.groupBy(first, second).count().collect()}
histograms.foreach(histogram => mergeToRedis(histogram))
```

This way its column based, it'd finish one column pair and then save it to the database.
I'd like it to be row based, take a few rows, generate histograms for all possible pairs, merge to the database and move on to the next batch.

Comment: update your question with what you have tried to do! your code per example

Comment: You should just be able to do `DataFrame.save(..., SaveMode.Append)` using the same file name over and over.